# MCU Selection For A Digital Signal

Tags: microcontroller, pic, signal, microchip

I am searching to choose a MCU which can realize a digital signal's high and low values (when the signal is rising and falling) and write them to an array like A={001101011011}. I don't need ADC channel for my MCU. The speed of MCU will be around at least 16 MHz. I don't need so many pins. So i have chosen some models and i desired to learn your suggestion or ideas about whether these MCUs can do my aim.

[PIC12F629-I/P](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41190G.pdf)

[PIC12F609-I/P](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41302D.pdf)

[PIC16F636-I/P](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41232D.pdf)

[LPC811M001JDH16J](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC81XM.pdf)

Thank you so much.

Comment: What else does your microcontroller do? Just looking at a signal and storing it in an array is completely useless (think signetics' write only memory) I guess there is some processing and output required too?

Comment: No, it just do this operation. Anything else actually. Are these enough for my aim?

Comment: I suspect you're going to get grief for asking too open a question. Pretty much any modern micro will do this (other than, obviously, low pin count devices). My take on this would be think about what tools are available; how easy is it to debug; once you go down the path of choosing the tools how easy would it be to use other micros for other jobs. IM not so HO PICs are good to avoid because their tools are (again IMHO) rubbish.

Comment: Just get an Arduino. They are supposed to be very good for beginners and there is a nice Stack Exchange group just for that: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/  I'm sure they would be very welcoming.

Answer (score 2):

Can't go wrong with a PIC. They've been around long enough and have good support. It should be really easy for you to find the software routines to achieve what you need to do using the PIC MCUs.

Digital IO pins are standard on all the PIC's, that what they're designed for. So reading a sequence of DIGITAL signals with the IO pins is a real piece of cake.

As a beginner, I would recommend you start with the cheap and widely available PIC to get your foot in the door. You don't want too many features initially since you are doing something very simple.

Answer (score 1):

According to your words, any MCU that has an external interrupt (not level changing interrupt, it must capable of sense the rising and falling edge) will do your job. But in my opinion, I suggest STM microcontrollers instead of PIC's. Because there are a lot of options in STM MCU family and their prices are almost same as the PIC's. Besides that STM's are 32 bit microcontrollers which is very useful if you need some exras in the future.

By the way, if you need DIP socket MCU for prototyping on breadboard you can use all of PIC's that you write on the post. All of them have an external interrupt pin like GP2 (you can find it on datasheet). Also you can buy one of ST's discovery kits for breadboard like M0 Discovery.

Comment: Yes, the other advantage of using ST's ARM processors are that, as long as you don't use their IDE, you can use any other manufacturer's ARM devices in the future. NXP, Atmel, TI and others also do good devices that would work with well chosen tool chains.

Comment: Thank you so much. Which parameter should i check for the I/O capture time in the datasheet?

Comment: The datasheet says that they have 200ns instruction time with 20MHz crystal oscillator. According to that you can calculate your capture routine time by take a look at the capture instructions. You should consider that all of the instructions take one cycle.